# I want to delete the folder after downloading it but after download further code is not executing

Tags: codeigniter, download, directory, delete-file

$download_path = 'admin_theme' . FOLDER_SEPRATOR . 'temp_folder' . FOLDER_SEPRATOR . $folder_name . '/';

```
        $this->load->library('zip');
        $this->zip->read_dir($download_path . '/');
        $this->zip->download($folder_name . '.zip');
        delete_files($new_folder, true, 1);
```

Comment: What is $new_folder?

Answer (score 0):

```
unlink($filename);
```

This will delete the file.

[See this manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.